# Lodash extract value from nested object

Tags: javascript, lodash, extract

I have below object which I am currently looping through to get item value. Currently I am using lodash _.forEach to achieve this. I am not sure what is best possible to create a new object with item name as key and value as value.

```
data =  [
  {
     "panels" : [
        {
          "title": "Panel 1",
          "items" : [
              {
                 "name": item1,
                 "value": 1
              }
              {
                 "name": item2,
                 "value": 2
              }
           ]
         },
         {
            "title": "Panel 2",
             "items" : [
              {
                 "name": item3,
                 "value": 3
              }
              {
                 "name": item4,
                 "value": 5
              }
           ]
         }
     ]
  }

  {
     "panels" : [
        {
          "title": "Panel 3"
          "items" : [
              {
                 "name": item5,
                 "value": 5
              }
              {
                 "name": item6,
                 "value": 6
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }  
]

  let values = [];
    _.forEach(data, (groups) => {
        _.forEach(groups.panels, (panel) => {
            _.forEach(panel.items, (item) => {
                  values[item.name] = item.value;                   
            });
        });
    });
    return values;
```

Is there any other way I can achieve this in more efficient way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a nested [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const data=[{panels:[{title:"Panel 1",items:[{name:"item1",value:1},{name:"item2",value:2}]},{title:"Panel 2",items:[{name:"item3",value:3},{name:"item4",value:5}]}]},{panels:[{title:"Panel 3",items:[{name:"item5",value:5},{name:"item6",value:6}]}]}];

const output = {};

for (const { panels } of data)
  for (const { items } of panels)
    for (const { name, value } of items)
      output[name] = value;

console.log(output)
```

Or,

You could use a chained [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) to get an array of items. Then `reduce` the items array to get an object with `name` as key and `value` as it's value

```js
const data=[{panels:[{title:"Panel 1",items:[{name:"item1",value:1},{name:"item2",value:2}]},{title:"Panel 2",items:[{name:"item3",value:3},{name:"item4",value:5}]}]},{panels:[{title:"Panel 3",items:[{name:"item5",value:5},{name:"item6",value:6}]}]}];

const output = data.flatMap(o => o.panels)
                   .flatMap(p => p.items)
                   .reduce((acc, o) => ({ ...acc, [o.name]: o.value }), {})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is a great solution. Is there any change you will be able to help me with one of my other questions which is related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085944/lodash-deep-filter-and-map-nested-object. I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @user4676307 you could use the chained `flatMap` to get the items and then use `find` on the array of items. `const found = data.flatMap(o => o.panels)
                   .flatMap(p => p.items).find(o => o.name === 'name')` Or you could use the `for...of` loop as mentioned in the answer and `return` as soon as a match is found

Comment: Added an answer in the linked question